# Spring MVC: Bind Input field to multiple properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to get Spring MVC to bind the value from one input field to multiple properties.
My use-case is a forum, that contains a form to create a new topic. That dialog actually create a topic and a post, which both have the same title, so only one input field exists for the title. If I copy the value myself in the controller method, using the "@Validated" annotation in the signature won't work, since the validator is called before I can copy the value, and so the title would still be missing in one field. Of course I can call the validator myself after copying the value, but if at all possible I would prefer if Spring would bind that value itself, just to get a clean solution  (and to learn if and how it is possible).

Best regards,
Christian

Comment: So, do you have what is generally called a command object?  A command object is generally a simple pojo (plain old java object) that will have setters and getters for all its attributes.  When title is set, just simply set two attributes instead of just one.  The setting of the attributes will occur before validation.  BTW, to clarify the command object is not unusually a domain object (like a topic or a post), but just a dto (data transfer object).  The actualy domain objects would be created/edited in your service object from the dto.

Comment: Yeah, I've got a "Topic"-object, which is the command-object, and it has a "Post"-object in it as a property. So in the jsp I could have <form:input path="title" /> or <form:input path="post.title" />. However, I want to have just one input, and let spring fill the other title as well. I was thinking about something like a PropertyEditor, or ConversionService, but those two don't seem to fit my use-case.

Comment: I would strongly urge you not to use a compound object as your command object.  Use a very simple class that has properties that can be set via property editors as needed, but generally very simple.  Then create your compound business/domain objects from your simple command object in a service.  I understand that you want to use a compound object as your command, but in my experience, I have not gotten it to work very well.